# HTML table set at 0px?

Tags: php, html

I've got a search query that returns results in a table - and if there are no results it returns the text no results

However the table acts as if there are no values in the cells?

[image: Screenshot of table]

Depending on the search, the table has different amounts of rows.

Why is it doing this?

Edit: Here is the complete code of the php file

```
<?php
mysql_connect("x", "x", "x") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("x") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Search results</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$query = $_GET['query'];

$min_length = 0;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT s.*
 , t.*
  FROM PalletSpaces s
  JOIN ProductTrans t
   ON s.PalletSpaceID = t.PalletSpace
 WHERE t.ProductName LIKE '%$query%' OR s.PalletSpace LIKE '%$query%';") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Pallet Space</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['t.ProductName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['s.PalletSpace'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['t.Quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['t.TransactionDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the css which is being applied to this table?

Comment: There is no css - but I'll post the query

Comment: Post your code, not image.

Comment: ok can you post the html for the table

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and see what your fieldnames really are. Also check your `view source` and see if there really IS anything in those cells. You'll probably find they're just `<td></td>`, because you're using the wrong `$row` keys.

Comment: you haven't posted the query

Comment: what is the condition of the `if` statement in which you are creating the table?

Comment: Please provide the complete `if-else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to like this:

```
SELECT  (t.ProductName) as Pname ,(s.PalletSpace) as PSpace,(t.Quantity) as Qty,(t.TransactionDate) as Transac
  FROM PalletSpaces s
  JOIN ProductTrans t
   ON s.PalletSpaceID = t.PalletSpace
 WHERE t.ProductName LIKE '%$query%' OR s.PalletSpace LIKE '%$query%';
```

Then change the field-names like match with the alias from the SQL Query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Pname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PSpace'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Qty'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Transac'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['PalletSpace'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['TransactionDate'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

If problem occur, array index use lower case.

Comment: That works - only there are two PalletSpace - and this returns the one in ProductTrans, not the one in PalletSpaces - which I need

Answer (score 0):

Please optimize your query as:

```
    SELECT 
       t.ProductName     as tProductName, 
       t.Quantity        as tQuantity, 
       t.TransactionDate as tTransactionDate, 
       s.PalletSpace     as sPalletSpace
    FROM PalletSpaces s
      JOIN ProductTrans t
      ON s.PalletSpaceID = t.PalletSpace
    WHERE t.ProductName LIKE '%$query%' OR s.PalletSpace LIKE '%$query%'
```

and please follow this psudo-code:

```
$results = mysql_query( $sql, $connectionObject );
if ($results){ //some results are returned from query.
   echo "<table>
           <tr>
             <th>Product Code</th>
             ...
          </tr>";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "  <td>" . $row['tProductName'] . "</td>";
     echo "  <td>" . $row['sPalletSpace'] . "</td>";
     echo "  <td>" . $row['tQuantity'] . "</td>";
     echo "  <td>" . $row['tTransactionDate'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
}else{  //no results returned from query.
   echo "No Results";
}
```

Hope, you will get the core idea from above code.